# List tables/Views used by a SSAS tabular Model in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Is there any way to List all  tables/Views used by SSAS tabular Model in SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are DMVs that might give you some information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions, TMSCHEMA_DATA_SOURCES sounds promising.